# How can I move the downloaded old files in minecraft to my new device?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

when I download the old files in minecraft the next thing i want to do is?
i want to know what is the next thing to do when I download them to have my whole worlds on my new device as they where before I move them

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you have your worlds downloaded and want to move them to a new device.

## Getting the saves to the device

If you haven't already, go ahead and send the save files to the new device. Some easy ways to do this are Google drive, Dropbox, or even e-mailing yourself. If none of these work for you, there are more solutions [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-ways-to-transfer-files-from-one-computer-to-another/).

## Adding them to Minecraft

First, you need to make sure the Minecraft launcher is installed on your new device and you have opened Minecraft Java-edition at least once.

Next, you need to locate the `.minecraft` folder. The location of it varies with the OS:

- **For Windows 10:** Press `⊞ Win + R` and type `%appdata%`
- **For MacOS:** Rout to `~/Library/Application Support`
- **For Linux:** Rout to your `/home` folder and be sure to show hidden files

Locate and open the `.minecraft` folder (might just be `minecraft`) and locate `saves`. Once inside the `saves` folder, all you have to do is copy the save files via your method of transferring them.